# How to get an Aurelia page to reload in a new tab

Tags: aurelia

I've got an Aurelia application loaded. When I do a CMD+click on a link, for example: https://localhost:4000/admin/list, a new tabs opens with this url. However, the application does not display. Instead, I get a blank page with the HTML contents:

<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>

How do I get the application in a new tab to reload the index.html page and then redirect to the desired route.

Note: in this process, the server is NOT hit with any requests. The browser (chrome or safari) caches the request.

Comment: Are you sure you have configured pushState navigation properly? http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: I think so:

config.options.pushState = true